# Why is the CheckedListBox DisplayMember not displaying?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to do something very simple - bind a CheckedListBox to a list of objects.

> **Class definition**

```
namespace Models
{
    public class Department
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

> **Minimal complete code sample to replicate the issue**
>
> (Create CheckedListBox clbDepartments first)

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Department> departmentList = new List<Department>();
        departmentList.Add(new Department { ID = 1, Description = "HR" });
        departmentList.Add(new Department { ID = 2, Description = "IT" });
        departmentList.Add(new Department { ID = 3, Description = "Sales" });

        var departmentBindingList = new BindingList<Department>(departmentList);
        var departmentSource = new BindingSource(departmentBindingList, null);
        clbDepartments.DisplayMember = "Description";
        clbDepartments.ValueMember = "ID";
        clbDepartments.DataSource = departmentSource;
    }
```

The list binds - I can see one item in the `CheckboxList` per item in the `List<Department>`.

But instead of displaying the value of the `"Description"` field, which is the `DisplayMember`, the list displays `"Models.Department"` for each item.

> **Expected Output**
>
> HR
>
> IT
>
> Sales

---

> **Actual Output**
>
> Models.Department
>
> Models.Department
>
> Models.Department

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm. This code used to work before. I don't know if the application was upgraded to a newer version of the framework. I wonder if it is version dependent?

Comment: There's definitely some very odd dark magic going on! This is a 2-year-old application, and the above code sample was used in older forms. Copy-pasting the same code in a new form resulted in the behavior above. I tried out the older screens (which WERE WORKING) and now they have the same issue!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should change the order.
First set the `DataSource` and then set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`

This should work:

```
clbDepartments.DataSource = departmentSource;
clbDepartments.DisplayMember = "Description";
clbDepartments.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Comment: It worked! It's odd though... TFS shows that the order was the same, yet it was somehow working.

Comment: The prevailing wisdom on Winforms is that setting DataSource last prevents a double paint of the control. CheckedListBox seems broken in this regard :(